# questions about tcp half-close

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, terminate, half-close

please see the following pic:

[image]

the client initiate a half-close request and get acknowledged,if i dont misunderstand what half-close means,the client *should not be able to send* any data afterwards, then how can it send back an **ACK** later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not the client *data* that is being sent, it the acknowledgement for the server data received after client does [`shutdown( fd, SHUT_WR )`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/shutdown.2.html), which means client will not *send* anymore, but can still *receive*. The `ACK` itself is part of the transport protocol, not the application.